# my Nexus 7 device is formatted accidentally

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-7, 4.3-jelly-bean

My device is Google Nexus 7 wifi only version.
I rooted this device by using Team Win Recovery Project.
I wanted to upgrade to android version 4.3 so I am looked at this [article](http://nexus7.wonderhowto.com/how-to/install-googles-official-4-3-jelly-bean-update-your-nexus-7-tablet-right-now-0148040) and [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Pmj5QJDY5ts#t=37)

I follow their instructions and I selected following items

- Dalvik Cache
- System
- Cache

and wiped them all.

But unfortunately, I found out that there is no file in my device with such name

```
AOSP-4.3-JWR66V-grouper-rooted_Androguide.zip
```

I need to get this file onto my device. But my device has no OS because I already wiped it.  Now I cannot access my device using my pc ( win 7 ).

Could anyone please give me suggestions on how can I solve it.

Comment: Yeah, the advantages of external SDCards clearly show here. As you don't have such: have you tried booting into recovery, and copying the file via ADB then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, you have a few options!

**Option One:** (I don't have an N7 anymore, so I don't remember if it supports `adb push` in TWRP. But I think it does) Boot into TWRP and use `adb` to push the file from your computer to your device. You can try to open a Windows CMD prompt or Linux Terminal Emulator, navigate to the local file, then do the following:

`adb push AOSP-4.3-JWR66V-grouper-rooted_Androguide.zip /sdcard/`

This will push the file to the `/sdcard/` directory - which should exist already (Even on a Nexus device).

**Option Two:** Boot the device to Fastboot/Bootloader Mode and flash any of the [Factory System Images](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#razorjss15r) via the fastboot tool. Because using fastboot can be intimidating. You could also use the [Nexus 7 Toolkit](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1809195) to automate the process.

This will put stock Android back on your device, and will also remove TWRP. Fortunately, you can use the Toolkit or Fastboot to reinstall TWRP immediately afterward.